# Tricky SQL algorithm, maybe there is a better way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not married to this algorithm so feel free to use any idea - this algorithm just illustrates the problem I am trying to solve. Suppose I have a table with "RecID", "Value" and "Result". I would like to net out the values for each row against other rows. So for example:

Let's say you have a table:

```
SELECT RecID, Value, Result
INTO #temp
FROM (
SELECT 1 as RecID, 60 as Value, NULL as result
UNION
SELECT 2 as RecID, -30 as Value, NULL as result
UNION
SELECT 4 as RecID, -200 as Value, NULL as result
UNION
SELECT 5 as RecID, -250 as Value, NULL as result
UNION
SELECT 6 as RecID, 300 as Value, NULL as result
) a
```

1) Sort this table by **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))** in ASC order so you will get:

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   NULL             
> 1,     60,    NULL       
> 4,     -200,  NULL
> 5,     -250,  NULL
> 6,     300,   NULL
> ```

2) PROCESSING ROW1 AND ROW2: Since the signs of the value are opposite (Row1 and Row2) take away the value of Row1 from Row1 and Row2 and write what is left to result. So take away -30 from RecID 1 and write to result, and add -30 to value in RecID 2 and write to result and sort again on **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))** :

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   0        <--
> 1,     60,    30       <--
> 4,     -200,  NULL
> 5,     -250,  NULL
> 6,     300,   NULL
> ```

3) PROCESSING ROW2 AND ROW3: Since the signs of the value are opposite (Row2 and Row3) take away 30 (the result of recid 1) from RecID 4 and write to result, take away that same 30 from RecID 1 and write to result and sort again on **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))** :

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   0
> 1,     60,    0        <--
> 4,     -200,  -170     <--
> 5,     -250,  NULL
> 6,     300,   NULL
> ```

4) PROCESSING ROW3 AND ROW4: Since signs of the value are the same for (Row3 and Row4) nothing needs to be done so copy the value to result and sort again on **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))**:

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   0
> 1,     60,    0
> 4,     -200,  -170     <--
> 5,     -250,  -250     <--
> 6,     300,   NULL
> ```

5) PROCESSING ROW3 AND ROW4: Since the signs of the value are opposite (Row3 and Row4) Take away -170 (result of recid 4) from 300 and write to result, sort again on **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))** and get:

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   0
> 1,     60,    0
> 4,     -200,  0       <--    
> 6,     300,   130     <--
> 5,     -250,  -250
> ```

6) PROCESSING ROW4 AND ROW5: Since the signs of the value are opposite (Row4 and Row5) Take away 130 (result of recid 6) from -250 and sort again on **COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value))** and get:

> ```
> RecID, Value, Result
> 2,     -30,   0
> 1,     60,    0
> 4,     -200,  0
> 6,     300,   0         <--
> 5,     -250,  -120      <--
> ```

Nothing more can be netted since the last values with opposite signs have already been netted.

Just not sure how to write something like this.

Comment: Would you like all rows to be updated to reflect the outcome of 7) or are you looking for something else?

Comment: So basically, you want to sum them, put the sum in one of the rows and set the others to zero?

Comment: @rbarryyoung - if you didn't have the last row then you'd end up at step 4 and have 2 non-zero rows.

Comment: I've removed your `UP FOR A CHALLENGE` addition to your subject line, It's totally inappropriate here, and SHOUTING your question is not an acceptable strategy for getting an answer here. Please don't use such techniques to try and get an answer faster. It's annoying. Edit the title instead to ask a better question that might get people to read your question. "Net out values" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can you give a link to the original formula of how "NET OUT" is calculated?

Comment: I don't believe there is a link. Basically you are taking out the negative values from the positive values and vice versa.

Comment: Every step but the first says sort of `ABS(result)`.  As far as I can tell this is not what you are doing, you are sorting on `COALESCE(ABS(result),ABS(value)), ABS(value)`.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Nicely presented algorithm. It all burns down to:

```
SELECT sum(values) AS result FROM #temp;
```

Returns `-120`. Or is there something else you want to achieve?

Comment: Good try, but if you omit the last row from the #temp table, the the table in step 4 should be returned. -170 would be left for RecId 4, and -250 for RecID 5. It shouldn't be just 1 value, it should be a set of rows with values that couldn't be netted out fully.